# Help with inner join query

Tags: php, mysql

I have two queries

```
$query1="SELECT staffid, COUNT(staffid) FROM enrll GROUP BY staffid ORDER BY COUNT(staffid) DESC";
$query2="SELECT staffid FROM staff as s WHERE auth = '1' AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT staffid from shdl as h where s.staffid=h.staffid and h.shdldt='".$unixdt."')";
```

Both queries are returning values in array, I want to find out those staffid from query1 having  inner join with query2 and values would be in array.

**NOTE** What would be combined query for both query to return final query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select e.staffid, count(e.staffid)
from enrll e
join staff s on e.staffid=s.staffid
where s.auth = '1' and NOT EXISTS ( 
    SELECT staffid from shdl as h 
    where s.staffid=h.staffid and h.shdldt='$unixdt')
group by e.staffid
ORDER BY COUNT(staffid) DESC
```

Comment: @john: isn't their is any need to write COUNT(e.staffid)? JOIN need to be defined as INNER JOIN?

Comment: @Aditii, you are right about `COUNT(e.staffid)`, it's a typo, fixed. And `join` is an alias for `inner join`, so it is OK.

Comment: @binaryLV Me too. But I don't have DB structure, so I wouldn't speculate on replacing this subquery with joins or something like that. So it is up to OP.